# Angular CLI can't create a new project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

How to creat a new project from angular-cli

There is a problem with angular-cli. The is has closed. I think there are still issue
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5543#event-1009616731

[image: How to creat a new project from angular-cli]

[image: Try again with new folder]
Try again with new folder

Comment: Please refer this site https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cli-quickstart.html

Comment: Thanks All. IT'S WORK

It can not work with any of the parent folders that have the file package.json

Comment: Checkout my answer for similar issue [https://stackoverflow.com/a/62499802/8297550](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62499802/8297550)

Answer (score 3):

There is either a package.json or angular-cli.json currently in the directory you are trying to create the new angular project in. Please remove that file and you should be able to `ng-new APP_NAME` afterward.

Comment: The second picture, I created a new folder, will be empty by default .... "ls -la" command to specify that no files exist there.

Comment: Please ensure you have met the minimum requirements as well. I see that your node version is high enough. What version of npm are you running?

`npm -v` will give you the information

You need to have npm 3.0.0 or higher installed on your system. So if you do not have 3.0.0 or higher install it first.

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly you need to have `Node` and `npm` installed on your system.
- Then install `angular-cli` using the command

  `npm install -g @angular/cli`
- Then make a new project using the command

  `ng new NEW_PROJECT`
- Finally run using the command

  `ng serve`

For more information please refer to these guidelines

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#installation
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2818

PS: check your `Node` and `npm` version compatibility with your `angular-cli` project version.

Comment: yes, i see but not success.

My info:
node: 6.10.0
os: linux x64
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.4

Comment: You cannot use the new command inside an Angular CLI project.
Look at the picture

Comment: that mean angular-cli project is already installed in your folder

Comment: command "ls -la", it's not create any files/folder... the folder is empty

Comment: its strange behavior, can you repeat the all steps once again in another folder ? so that we can figure out whats the problem and where ?