# Can't create a Project with Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

A few days ago I created a new project with **Angular CLI** and everything worked fine. I'm not able to create any new project now. Below is the error logs in cmd:

```
 c:\Users\Jesper\Desktop>ng new mytestapp
? Would you like to add Angular routing? Yes
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
CREATE mytestapp/angular.json (3795 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/package.json (1316 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/README.md (1026 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/tsconfig.json (408 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/tslint.json (2837 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/.editorconfig (245 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/.gitignore (503 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/favicon.ico (5430 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/index.html (296 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/polyfills.ts (3234 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/browserslist (388 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/karma.conf.js (964 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/tsconfig.app.json (166 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/tsconfig.spec.json (256 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/tslint.json (314 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/app/app-routing.module.ts (245 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/app/app.module.ts (393 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/app/app.component.html (1173 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (1104 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/app/app.component.ts (213 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/e2e/protractor.conf.js (752 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json (213 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (305 bytes)
CREATE mytestapp/e2e/src/app.po.ts (208 bytes)
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @schematics/update@0.10.5
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of '@angular/cli'
npm ERR! notarget

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-09T00_31_49_304Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

Here is the output from `ng version`:

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.4
Node: 10.13.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.10.4
@angular-devkit/core         7.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.0.4
@schematics/angular          7.0.4
@schematics/update           0.10.4
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.1.3
```

How come this problem has occurred suddenly and how do I fix it?

Comment: Is angular-cli installed globally?

Comment: @Kai I typed `npm list -g` in cmd and I found `@angular/cli@7.0.4` in the list, so it seems like it is?

Comment: Are there any package.json or other Angular files in the folder you are in (desktop)?

Comment: @DeborahK The node_modules folder is at C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules. Inside this folder, there is no package.json, but there is one at `@angular/cli/package.json`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular CLI can't create a new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946571/angular-cli-cant-create-a-new-project)

Comment: try deleting your node_modules folder and try again

Comment: (1) try creating a project with "ng new" only... it will ask you for name, routing etc. (2) if you do ng new in a different folder, other than "c:\Users\Jesper\Desktop"... do you get the same message ?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem, only in my case, the process froze following the circular-son download. I killed it and ran it again and it worked fine.