# Angular ng new returns package install failed error - compiler.umd.js missing

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to learn Angular and am following an online tutorial. However, I can't seem to get past creating a new project with ng new. I am running node v10.16.0 and npm 6.9.0 on Windows 7. I get the following error in the log:

```
15177 verbose cwd C:\Personal documents\Angular\myProject
15178 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
15179 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--quiet"
15180 verbose node v10.16.0
15181 verbose npm  v6.9.0
15182 error path C:\Personal documents\Angular\myProject\node_modules\.staging\typescript-f4316380\lib\lib.dom.d.ts
15183 error code EPERM
15184 error errno -4048
15185 error syscall unlink
15186 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Personal documents\Angular\myProject\node_modules\.staging\typescript-f4316380\lib\lib.dom.d.ts'
15186 error  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Personal documents\Angular\myProject\node_modules\.staging\typescript-f4316380\lib\lib.dom.d.ts']
15186 error   cause:
15186 error    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Personal documents\Angular\myProject\node_modules\.staging\typescript-f4316380\lib\lib.dom.d.ts'
15186 error      errno: -4048,
15186 error      code: 'EPERM',
15186 error      syscall: 'unlink',
15186 error      path:
15186 error       'C:\\Personal documents\\Angular\\myProject\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-f4316380\\lib\\lib.dom.d.ts' },
15186 error   stack:
15186 error    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\\Personal documents\\Angular\\myProject\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-f4316380\\lib\\lib.dom.d.ts\'',
15186 error   errno: -4048,
15186 error   code: 'EPERM',
15186 error   syscall: 'unlink',
15186 error   path:
15186 error    'C:\\Personal documents\\Angular\\myProject\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-f4316380\\lib\\lib.dom.d.ts',
15186 error   parent: '@angular-devkit/build-optimizer' }
15187 error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
15187 error It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
15187 error or that you lack permissions to access it.
15187 error
15187 error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
15187 error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
15187 error the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
15188 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]
```

I followed the path specified above and the lib folders are empty. I tried reinstalling node, reinstalling angular, clearing the cache with --force, running as administrator, restarting. Nothing is helping.

Please note that I am a complete noob at this and am just trying to learn the framework, which right now seems impossible to work with.

I expect the packages to install and the project to be created without issues.

Comment: What did you try to fix this error? Have you looked for information about it?

Comment: if you are using angular v8 you need node v12, but this seem like npm are having problems to write one package

Comment: Like I said, I tried  reinstalling node, reinstalling angular, clearing the cache with --force, running as administrator, restarting. Those are the solutions I managed to find and that did not work

Comment: ng new yourProject --force=true ? if you have the latest version of angular(8.0.2) you need to install node 12.x tha are not in LTS

Comment: @Vash72 I didn't know that, I though we were supposed to use LTS. I will try node 12

Comment: @NikaBo for me the problem is that npm aren't able to write in some directory, you can try with --force=true

Comment: I doubt it's a version issue, the stack trace says `The operation was rejected by your operating system. It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus), error or that you lack permissions to access it.`

Comment: @NikaBo you can even try ng new yourProject --skipInstall=true, so no node_modules will be installed and than run npm install --force

Comment: I installed node 12 but still couldn't get the package install to finish. --force = true didn't help either. I manged to manually update the typescript libraries through npm so that error is gone. Now i get issues with  core.umd.js

Comment: @Vash72 Ok, I think ng new yourProject --skipInstall=true worked. At least no errors this time. Will the project be functional though?

Comment: @NikaBo Yes it will work fine, the problem is that for some reason when angular/cli (ng) run npm install by itself, it have problem with package writing , that with npm install --force you don't have

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For some reasons when angular/cli (ng) run npm install by itself, it have problem with packages writing, so you can run

```
ng new yourProject --skipInstall=true
```

so angular/cli will not install any node packages and then run

```
npm install --force
```

to install it by yourself

Comment: Node version 18 does not recognize --skipInstall

Answer (score 0):

I've faced like this issue and the solution was:

1. Go to **Edit the system environment variables**.
2. Under **User variables for User** ==> **Path**, Make sure **C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm** its above all, and make sure you are
   add current user directory.

**Note**: If you don't have current user directory you have to create it.

[image]

3.Under **System variables** ==> **Path**, Make sure **C:\Program Files\nodejs** its above all.

[image]

4. Open **Command Prompt** as **user** ==> **npm cache clean --force**.
5. **npm install -g npm@lates**t.
6. **ng new yourApp**.
7. **ng serve --open**.

Answer (score -1):

are you working offline? you need to be online, so that npm can download the dependencies for the project.

Comment: the error show clearly means npm is running (so he is online) but can't write some package, and to be honest you don't even need to be online if npm have the package already cached  it will get them from the cache