# Angular 9 ng new stuck at installing packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I have just installed the node version 12.16.1 the  LTS and
 angular cli version 9.0.3.
 At the time of creating new project with cli all files in root folder are generating but it is stuck at the part of installing node packages.

Is anybody facing the same issue? Please help how can we resolve it.

Comment: at times it takes some time to install all the packages, if you feel like stuck you can cancel and do npm install again and give it a try.

Comment: Now, I am waiting for more than 30 minutes to download it. How let me try to cancel it doing npm I.

Comment: Yes it worked. But we need to find a reason why it didn't work during my new

Comment: reinstall node.. then set node path environment variable in windows system, reinstall angular CLI with `-g` global. and checkout some of the firewall or anti-virus system that can block some of services during installation.. these are some of the points you need to take care.

Comment: I sloved this issue, could you checkout my answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/62499802/8297550](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62499802/8297550)

Answer (score 5):

I changed directory and then run these command and it worked for me

`sudo npm cache clean --force`

`sudo npm cache verify`

`sudo npm i npm@latest -g`

`ng new my-project`

---

Another Solution:

Cancel the installing packages with `ctrl+c`

and then go to the files of project and run command `npm install`

This also worked for me

Answer (score 4):

1. Run command `npm i -g npm@latest`
2. Run command `npm i -g @angular/cli@latest`

It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Every time you create a new project the angular suppose to download huge chunks of file of size around 500mb, all the time that is been taken is actually the time taken to download those file in the background. A good internet connection is the solution.

Comment: I'm starting with angular I hope you don't have to download all those packages for every app you want to create that would be ridiculous...

Comment: My connection is slow and I am facing the same issue. I just have to wait a little longer.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue quite a few times.
Try using: ng new project_name --skip-install

And then, go to the file and do npm install

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.

I tried everything. Reinstallation of node several times. Latest version didn't change anything. Stuck at `Installing packages (npm)...`

I was running node.js within a virtual machine. Only 1 gig of memory was allocated to the VM. Allocating more memory (from 1 gig to 4 gig) solved the problem. if there is not enough memory, node.js does not complain but seems stuck.

I can reproduce the problem. Now with 4 gig instead of 1 gig, `ng new app` took only 30 seconds.

Comment: Hello sir, can you please tell me how to allocate more memory for the VM.

Comment: @KSSabarinathan:You have to allocate more memory to Virtual Box or VMware VM.  To be found within the config of the VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up one workspace (one folder) for all your applications, by running

```
ng new your_workspace --create-application false
```

and then create your new apps inside this workspace

```
cd your_workspace

ng generate application testApp
```

Maybe it helps to your needs