# Angular 'ng new' command taking forever; never completes installing packages

Tags: angularjs, angular

I'm having issues with the 'ng new [workspace-name-here]' command when I'm trying to just create a new Angular project. It just hangs at the "Installing packages (npm)..." text for several minutes, upto a half hour or longer in the few times I've tried it tonight. I never get beyond this point.

I hear it takes a notoriously long time, from nearly every stack overflow post or Udemy instruction over the last three or four years, but nothing's stuck.

I've tried running the command line as administrator, which was what my course I'm in suggested I do.

I've also found a few old Stack Overflow questions where people sounded like they had the same issue, but the provided solutions were more or less 'it takes time. Just wait it out'.

I've seen this question here: [Angular 9 ng new stuck at installing packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60388160/angular-9-ng-new-stuck-at-installing-packages) which more or less says 'just wait it out. It WILL take a long time.', as well as the following on git, which says 'this is an issue with npm. Do something about your npm install'
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3032

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was trying to run this command on an external harddrive I'd been dedicating to other projects- and this command didn't like being directed to the harddrive. Once I changed to B:/, it worked totally fine.